# paper.js union difference and intersection

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, vector-graphics, inkscape

I'm working on a project in paper.js where I need to create new paths based on the intersection, difference and union of two others. I did some digging and found the mathematical function that interpolates a cubic bezier spline, but I was wondering if there were any javascript libraries that did svg-like vector arithmetic. If anything, I'll copy inkscape's and convert it to javascript, but you never know.
Anyway, the mathematical function for interpolating cubic beziers is as follows:

```
Pointx = (Ax * percent^3) + (Bx * 3 * (percent^2 * (1-percent))) + (Cx * 3 * (percent * (1-percent)^2)) + (Dx * (1-percent)^3)
Pointy = (Ay * percent^3) + (By * 3 * (percent^2 * (1-percent))) + (Cy * 3 * (percent * (1-percent)^2)) + (Dy * (1-percent)^3)
```

Where A, B, C and D are the points for the curve. A is the start, D is the end, and B and C are the "control points" that manipulate the curvature between A and D. The `percent` is how far along the curve to calculate on a scale from 0 to 1.

So it would be pretty trivial coming up with an interpolation function that returns a point for a provided bezier and a percentage along the bezier. Finding the inverse - a percentage(s) for a given point (or x value or y value) would be difficult. Or even more difficult, where two beziers intersect (I'm not very good at math). I'm hoping that's what inkscape's functions provide.

Are there any javascript libraries that can do this kind of vector interpolation quickly? If not, I'll post the algorithm I come up with here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is something called *[Boolean Operations on Polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons)*

Paper.js seems to now use fairly nice BoolOps and they deal directly with bezier curves. This should be the first choice if you ask me. Here's a nice [example](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/).

In another scenario, you could polygonize the shapes using [De-Casteljau algorithm](https://gist.github.com/Phrogz/845901) and feed them into [Javascript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Home/). If you use high sampling the visual result is identical to true curves, but you lose the curvy nature of the paths.

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't go so far as to say this is a duplicate question I believe you will find great insight from the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008006/draw-good-looking-bezier-curve-through-random-points) as it is quite similar.

I did find one other resource that is not mentioned amongst the answers to that question here:
http://13thparallel.com/archive/bezier-curves/

Other than that the best resource that was mentioned in that question is here:
http://blog.mackerron.com/2011/01/01/javascript-cubic-splines/

Both these resources detail specific functions that will do what you are looking for. While they are not quite "libraries" the code will be easily ported to your project for your purposes.

Comment: Sadly, those links are for rendering the line. this function will not render at steady intervals as shown from one of those links:
[link](http://13thparallel.com/archive/bezier-curves/example3.htm)
What I really want, though, it to find the point where they intersect. I'll update with my findings here soon.